# Map APIs and REST

Tags: rest, google-maps-api-3, bing-maps, here-api

I'm currently doing an investigation into the use of APIs with mobile and web applications and I've recently stumbled across something called Representational State Transfer (REST).

It seems that MSDN Bing API documents this quite well, but Google Maps API doesn't.

Does anyone know if this interface is just used by Bing or could it be implemented with the use of Google Maps API as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find Google Maps API documentation at this link, but it only describes how to interface with the API in order to use the Maps service;
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/